# When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?

Tags: security, gui, sudo, root, policykit

There are two general ways to run applications graphically as root (or, more generally, as another user). Programs like [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=gksu&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/), [`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=gksudo&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/), and [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=kdesudo&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/) are graphical frontends for [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=sudo&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%252F). In contrast, [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=pkexec&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%252F) is a graphical frontend for [PolicyKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit).

When *manually* running programs as root (or as another, non-root user), what are the advantages/disadvantages (if any) of using `pkexec`, compared to the more traditional method of using a `sudo` frontend?

Comment: See also [Why is gksu no-longer installed by default? (in 13.04 Raring)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default/284717#284717)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252962/is-there-a-desktop-neutral-gksudo

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Is sudo -i less secure than pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647963/is-sudo-i-less-secure-than-pkexec)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

PolicyKit is more configurable, though `pkexec` doesn't make use of this configurability.  Also, `pkexec` show the user the full path of the program that will be started, to that the user is a bit more sure what will happen. The so-called 'policies` of PolicyKit can be used to set more advances settings. For example, whether the password should be remembered.

Something I got from the `pkexec` manual:

> The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal
>   known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID
>   environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking
>   pkexec. As a result, pkexec will not allow you to run e.g. X11
>   applications as another user since the $DISPLAY environment variable
>   is not set.

More information on *policies* or *action definitions* from the `pkexec` manual:

> ```
>    To specify what kind of authorization is needed to execute the program
>    /usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate as another user, simply write an action
>    definition file like this
>
>        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>        <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
>         "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
>         "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
>        <policyconfig>
>
>          <vendor>Examples for the PolicyKit Project</vendor>
>          <vendor_url>http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/PolicyKit/</vendor_url>
>
>          <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.example.pkexec.run-frobnicate">
>            <description>Run the PolicyKit example program Frobnicate</description>
>            <description xml:lang="da">Kør PolicyKit eksemplet Frobnicate</description>
>            <message>Authentication is required to run the PolicyKit example program Frobnicate</message>
>            <message xml:lang="da">Autorisering er påkrævet for at afvikle PolicyKit eksemplet Frobnicate</message>
>            <icon_name>audio-x-generic</icon_name>
>            <defaults>
>              <allow_any>no</allow_any>
>              <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
>              <allow_active>auth_self_keep</allow_active>
>            </defaults>
>            <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate</annotate>
>          </action>
>
>        </policyconfig>
>
>    and drop it in the /usr/share/polkit-1/actions directory under a
>    suitable name (e.g. matching the namespace of the action). Note that in
>    addition to specifying the program, the authentication message,
>    description, icon and defaults can be specified. For example, for the
>    action defined above, the following authentication dialog will be
>    shown:
>
>        [IMAGE][2]
>
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>            |                     Authenticate                     [X] |
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>            |                                                          |
>            |  [Icon]  Authentication is required to run the PolicyKit |
>            |          example program Frobnicate                      |
>            |                                                          |
>            |          An application is attempting to perform an      |
>            |          action that requires privileges. Authentication |
>            |          is required to perform this action.             |
>            |                                                          |
>            |          Password: [__________________________________]  |
>            |                                                          |
>            | [V] Details:                                             |
>            |  Command: /usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate                 |
>            |  Run As:  Super User (root)                              |
>            |  Action:  org.fd.pk.example.pkexec.run-frobnicate        |
>            |  Vendor:  Examples for the PolicyKit Project             |
>            |                                                          |
>            |                                  [Cancel] [Authenticate] |
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>
>    If the user is using the da_DK locale, the dialog looks like this:
>
>        [IMAGE][3]
>
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>            |                     Autorisering                     [X] |
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>            |                                                          |
>            |  [Icon]  Autorisering er påkrævet for at afvikle         |
>            |          PolicyKit eksemplet Frobnicate                  |
>            |                                                          |
>            |          Et program forsøger at udføre en handling der   |
>            |          kræver privilegier. Autorisering er påkrævet.   |
>            |                                                          |
>            |          Kodeord: [___________________________________]  |
>            |                                                          |
>            | [V] Detaljer:                                            |
>            |  Bruger:   Super User (root)                             |
>            |  Program:  /usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate                |
>            |  Handling: org.fd.pk.example.pkexec.run-frobnicate       |
>            |  Vendor:   Examples for the PolicyKit Project            |
>            |                                                          |
>            |                                [Annullér] [Autorisering] |
>            +----------------------------------------------------------+
>
>    Note that pkexec does no validation of the ARGUMENTS passed to PROGRAM.
>    In the normal case (where administrator authentication is required
>    every time pkexec is used), this is not a problem since if the user is
>    an administrator he might as well just run pkexec bash to get root.
>
>    However, if an action is used for which the user can retain
>    authorization (or if the user is implicitly authorized), such as with
>    pk-example-frobnicate above, this could be a security hole. Therefore,
>    as a rule of thumb, programs for which the default required
>    authorization is changed, should never implicitly trust user input
>    (e.g. like any other well-written suid program).
> ```

Comment: I guess I should have said *there are two to run applications as root with graphical authentication*. I had assumed there was a way to use `pkexec` to run graphical applications (I had just never done so...). Your answer explains why there is not (or at least why a custom environment has to be specified, to do it).

Comment: I do have one question about your answer, though--when a program is run as root with `pkexec`, in what sense can it capabilities ("permissions") be constrained? I grant a program the ability to do anything when I run it with `sudo` or a `sudo` frontend...in what sense does running a program as root with `pkexec` not also do this?

Comment: By granting it specific permissions only with a special policy. For example, the software centre uses PolicyKit to install/remove software, and when you grant it permission, it can use that permissions to install or remove software, and nothing else than that.

Comment: I understand that *PolicyKit* is used to allow programs to perform only specific types of actions. But does `pkexec` facilitate that, or does `pkexec` just run things as root with unrestricted abilities? The `pkexec` manual excerpt you included in your answer documents how to write rules to determine who can run a program as root (or as another, non-root user), rather than what the program can do.

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: In that case, while PolicyKit itself is more configurable than `sudo` and its frontends, in that PolicyKit can do more things that just run a program as `root` or another user, it seems that `pkexec` itself is not really more configurable than `sudo` and its frontends, right? You said, "When using `sudo`, `gksudo`, `gksu`, ... you immediately grant the program (allmost) all permissions, with wich it can cause serious damage to your system." But whereas PolicyKit can be used to grant a running program that uses PolicyKit more limited abilities, it seems that doesn't apply at all to `pkexec`.

Comment: No, `pkexec` just  uses the standard `exec` policy of PolicyKit, so what you said is more or less correct.

Comment: I want to accept your answer, as it provides a lot of good information. But I feel that it's very misleading, because it says that `pkexec` is more configurable than `sudo`, and given the discussion we've had here in the comments, that does not seem to be the case. Would you consider editing your answer to either explicate `sudo`'s configurability and compare/contrast it to `pkexec`'s, or edit your answer to say that the difference is something other than configurability?

Comment: Another (very related) problem: You say that when using `sudo` or a `sudo` frontend I "immediately grant the program...all permissions...". But as you've admitted, that is also the case **100% of the time when anybody uses `pkexec`**.

Comment: @EliahKagan Done.

Comment: "simply write" and then a chunk of XML.  I needed that laugh.

Comment: so making a `pkexec` alias as explained here http://askubuntu.com/a/332847/46437 will make is less safe? but will it still be more safe than `gksudo`? and instead of an alias, a script with root privileges could be safer?

Comment: FYI `pkexec` **can** run GUI without configuration: http://askubuntu.com/a/332847/89385

Answer (score 16):

With sudo you can set per user and per program policies about wether to retain or reset the callers environment in the context of sudo. The env_reset policy is set by default.

You can't run graphical applications via pkexec without explicitly configuring it to do so. Because this is merely a result of the environment reset this is obviously true for sudo as well. Note however thet neither pkexec nor sudo can prevent a malevolent application running as root to retrieve all neccessary information from the display managers or the users X11-cookie file. The latter, both or similiar, may even be done by non root applications depending on circumstances.

Sudo does not require explicit listings of users. Listing any user group or even setting a permission for all users in general can be done. The target_pw directive allows those users to authenticate with the credentials of the user in whoose context they want to run an application, i.e. root. Apart from that the equally traditional su (su / gtksu / kdesu) program can be used to do the very same without special configuration.

sudo, too, allows the user to remain authenticated for a specified time.  The option is named timeout, configurable globally, per user, or per application. Authentication can be retained per tty or globally per user.

While pkexec may do no validation of the ARGUMENTS passed to PROGRAM, sudo does indeed have this feature. Admitted though, you can easily mess up with this, and it is normally not done.

You can tweak a little how you want programs to be run via pkexec: icon, text to display, you can even have localization stuff and all that. Depending on circumstances this can be nifty indeed. Sad though, that someone felt the need to reinvent the wheel for this feature. This would probably be something to put into the graphical gtksudo/kdesu wrappers.

Policykit is only a centralized configuration framework then. Unfortunately not a pretty one. PKs XML-Files are way more complicated than anything an app could provide natively short of binary files. And no one would be so looney to use binary ... oh gconf ... never mind.

Comment: I downvoted because this post isn't really an answer, it's a criticism of another answer. If you feel that it usually a better choice to use sudo over pkexec, say so, explaining your point with these rebuttals.

Comment: Thanks Paul, for lots of helpful analysis here!  But I also agree with Flimm.  Can you start off with a simple answer to the question as asked?

Comment: No, `pkexec` **can** run GUI without configuring: http://askubuntu.com/a/332847/89385

Answer (score 8):

A few things how `pkexec` is different from `sudo` and its frontends:

1. You can't run graphical applications via `pkexec` without explicitly configuring it to do so.
2. You can tweak a little how you want programs to be run via `pkexec`: icon, text to display, whether to remember the password or not, whether to allow it to run graphically and some more.
3. Anybody can run "Run as" a superuser (provided they can authenticate as such), with `sudo` you have to be listed in the `sudoers` file as *admin*.
4. `gksudo` locks the keyboard, mouse, and focus when asking for a password, `pkexec` doesn't. In both cases [the keystrokes are sniffable though](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html).
5. With `pkexec` you work in a slightly more sanitized environment.

Try for example:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo cat README
# and now the same with pkexec
pkexec cat README
# nice, huh?
```

Comment: Good point (#3) about how you can authenticate as other users' to run programs as `root` with `pkexec`. Is it configurable, which users can use `pkexec` at all (even if they know the password of another user who is permitted to do so)? `su` is configurable in this way. When I attempt to `su` to another non-`root` user as `guest` on an Oneiric system, it tells me I am not permitted to do so. (In contrast, when I try to use `pkexec` as `guest` on Oneiric or Precise, I get what looks like an assertion error, which I may soon report as a bug, as I shouldn't get that even if it isn't allowed.)

Comment: But `sudo` and its frontends can also be tweaked as described in point 2. You can run a program with `gksu` or `gksudo` [displaying customized text](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/7685/customdescriptionforgks.png), stop needing some users' passwords by editing `/etc/sudoers` (with `visudo`), and change how long they are remembered in the sense of changing how long it takes for sudo to time out (though I am not sure how to do this on Ubuntu, which is configured so that the questions of whether or not `sudo` needs a password, and how long until it will need one again, are terminal-specific).

Comment: #4 is not true if you're using GNOME Shell.

Comment: No, `pkexec` **can** run GUI without configuring: http://askubuntu.com/a/332847/89385