# Why isn't gksu in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, default, default-programs, gksu

I don't know if this is a bug or it's their decision? but why isn't it installed by default?

Comment: It's on the live CD but not there when installed.

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo (seems like we should be using pkexec in the future)