# Can I use pkexec in a python script or a .desktop file?

Tags: python, gksu, .desktop, pkexec

From the following questions

- [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04)
- [When to use pkexec vs. gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo)

we see that gksu will no longer be supported in the long term, and it will not be installed by default from >= 13.04. Instead we should use pkexec which does its job fine for non-graphical applications but not for apllications on the GUI:

```
pkexec gedit
```

when replacing gksu in a .desktop file

```
EXEC=pkexec /usr/bin/gedit
```

or when I run a python script to run a graphical application with root permissions I get the following error:

```
>>>subprocess.Popen(['pkexec','gedit'])
** (gedit:3203): WARNING **: Could not open X display
```

How would I have to re-write my scripts or my .desktop files to support an authentication dialog and run an application as root if I should not have it depend on gksu?

Comment: One of the updates to `sudo` I saw said something about integrating support for gksu into sudo. Another thing to look at is `sudo -A` which according to the man page launches a (possibly) graphical login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a `.policy` action file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/`. It's  conventional to name action files in a "vendor hierarchical" way, such as `com.ubuntu.pkexec.gparted.policy` or `org.debian.apt.policy`

Then paste the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">

<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-[Short Program Name]">
    <description>Run [Full Program Name]</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run [Full Program Name]</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">[Full Program Path]</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

Replace `[Short/Full Program Name/Path]` with appropriate values, for example `gedit`, `gedit Text Editor` and `/usr/bin/gedit`.  `<action id>` value does not need to match the chosen filename (and a single file can contain multiple actions), but conventionally filename is the prefix for all its actions.

After saving the file the specific program would run with X and GUI and such.

Another fix seems to be:
Add the following line in /etc/pam.d/polkit-1:

> session optional pam_xauth.so

Answer (score 1):

Yet another fix for user scripts: Determine the appropriate environment variables inside your script.

You could use a snippet like the following one to do this:

```
getXuser() {
        user=`pinky -fw | awk '{ if ($2 == ":'$displaynum'" || $(NF) == ":'$displaynum'" ) { print $1; exit; } }'`
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then
                startx=`pgrep -n startx`
                if [ x"$startx" != x"" ]; then
                        user=`ps -o user --no-headers $startx`
                fi
        fi
        if [ x"$user" = x"" ]; then
               user=$(pinky -fw | awk '{ print $1; exit; }')
        fi
        if [ x"$user" != x"" ]; then
                userhome=`getent passwd $user | cut -d: -f6`
                export XAUTHORITY=$userhome/.Xauthority
        else
                export XAUTHORITY=""
        fi
        export XUSER=$user
}


for x in /tmp/.X11-unix/*; do
   displaynum=`echo $x | sed s#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##`
   getXuser;
      if [ x"$XAUTHORITY" != x"" ]; then
        export DISPLAY=":$displaynum"
      fi
done
```

(based on the ACPI `getXuser` function)

If you find your `.desktop` file still not working you could try wrapping your `pkexec commandline` in a `sh` snippet, e.g.:

```
Exec=sh -c "pkexec --user root script_that_needs_root.sh"
```

The last problem is a known bug, apparently:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=690339

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9373

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650038

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686059