# When should I use pkexec and when sudo -i?

Tags: permissions, sudo, pkexec

I wrote an answer advising the use of `sudo -i nautilus`. I know that [`gksu` is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default), and I was under the impression that `sudo -i` is how we should run graphical applications as root without [killing kittens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus?rq=1), but someone commented '`pkexec` is the new `gksu`'. My understanding is that `pkexec` is not the same as using any form of `sudo`:

[When to use pkexec vs gksu/gksudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo)

and requires setting up, especially to use with graphical applications:

[How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec)

When I do `sudo -i` everything always works, so why should I go to the trouble of configuring `pkexec`? I can see that for writing a script that launches something as root I would need to do it:

[Can I use pkexec in a Python Script or .desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288087/can-i-use-pkexec-in-a-python-script-or-a-desktop-file)

But otherwise, what do I gain from using `pkexec`? When should I use these commands? What is currently the best practice for opening graphical applications as root?

(I already read the... `man` pages, but I am feeling no wiser.)

Comment: I personally ignore the deprecation and always install `gksu` on every system to run GUI apps with `gksudo` if needed. Nothing else.

Comment: Here is a similar (not quite a dupe) question, the answer by serg has good links to other questions on this that may interest you http://askubuntu.com/questions/704619/how-gui-based-apps-ask-for-root-password-without-gksudo-installed FYI I still use `gksu` too, just a habit I guess.

Comment: @MarkKirby I upvoted Serg's answer there but I already read those links (one is in my question) and I can hardly read that question! >_<

Comment: Related: [This old post on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6634/37165) had relevant discussion and the most upvoted answer suggested `sudo -i` is a safe solution; But not much explained for `pkexec`.

Comment: In the case of using GUI text editors to edit files as root, what about using `sudoedit` (AKA `sudo -e`)?

Comment: @edwinksl you meant you could set a graphical editor as default for `sudoedit`? Interesting idea

Comment: @Zanna Yeah, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356443/6949 for example.

Answer (score 3):

The basic use is the same - the programs in question allow you to run other programs as another user, usually root. The difference, however, between `sudo` variants and `pkexec` is that `sudo` gives a program total control over everything, while with `pkexec` you have a much more fine grained control by defining a policy for each program.

If you trust the programs that you run, sudo is perfectly fine. If you want to really lock down everything and permit programs to do only what you allow them to, then use `pkexec` that comes along with [polkit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/polkit.8.html).

While the idea behind `pkexec` is nice, I wouldn't go as far as calling it the next `gksu`, due to the complex set up needed.

Reference: [the difference between sudo and pkexec on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pkexec-and-sudo/answer/Clem-Cole?srid=dVzV).