# (gedit:5596): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!. How to solve this error?

Tags: gedit

When I am trying to edit some files I am getting this warning. How can I resolve this error.

```
(gedit:5596): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/user/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

Comment: that happens when you run `sudo gedit`, which you should avoid. Use `sudo -i` then `gedit` and remember to `exit` at the end, if you actually need to use gedit with root privileges

Answer (score 5):

If you want to not see the error, try `sudo -i gedit` in the future.

You are attempting to run gedit via sudo without inheriting the root user's environment settings and are instead using them from the current user.  The current user is not root and root is not running ibus, so you definitely should be seeing that error.

Comment: `sudo -i gedit` didn't work. Does it change the directory? On the other hand `gksu gedit` and `pkexec gedit` did work. I ran all three commands from within the user's home directory on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the one answer recommending "sudo gedit" is technically incorrect. You need to use "gksu ..." for graphical environments (GUI).

```
gksu gedit some_file_name
```

and

```
gksu nautilus /some_directory
```

are the accepted standards.

Starting with **Ubuntu 17.04** you should use `pkexec` instead of `gksu`.

Comment: No, `sudo -i` is perfectly fine for GUI applications. The problem with plain `sudo` is that it does not reset some environment variables, causing problems. `sudo -i` gives a clean root environment.

Comment: @muru I didn't reference `sudo -i` in my answer as I saw the one without I'll change it from two to one... Thanks.

Comment: `gksu` is already deprecated (although fine to use) and not installed by default. `pkexec` requires configuration. `sudo -i` is probably best, but [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/802649/when-should-i-use-pkexec-and-when-sudo-i) is still waiting for a good answer...

Comment: @Zanna A chevron to your question which is a great one. Personally I use a script called `gsu` that calls `pkexec` and writes a record to a log file of every file edited. The log file will hopefully help me migrate code changes to new installs down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the chevron :) sounds like a useful script :D