# How to change gnome shell theme in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I want to change gnome shell theme, I use ubuntu 14.10 and user extensions don't work, can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use the [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension (make sure it is enabled):
[image: make sure it is enabled]

and [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/):
[image: Look for the Shell Theme entry]

You can also change the theme from command line, by examining things using `dconf-editor`, you can use `gsettings` to change the theme - so for Gnome 3.8 with the User Themes extension, this sets the theme to "Zukitwo":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name "Zukitwo"
```

Resets the theme:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name
```

Gets the current theme's name

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name
```

If you have downloaded the theme from somewhere (e.g. a zip from [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Zukitwo-203936861)), put the theme's directory in `~/.local/share/themes` (if it does not exist, create it). Note the theme won't work if it does not contain a `gnome-shell` folder with the Gnome shell theme - in which case you can make a similar one using [Elegance colours](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Elegance-Colors-305966388) or similar.

---

> **WARNING:** This method is harder to undo, and will also change the theme for the login screen (if the theme does not work it is probably
>   then more likely to go wrong...)

Otherwise *(you'll may want to do this by running `nautilus` as root - if so use [`pkexec`/`gksudo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/79639/178596))*, you can copy the contents `gnome-shell` bit of the theme to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` - beforehand make sure you backup the existing theme:

```
sudo cp -r "/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme" "/usr/share/gnome-shell/themeBACKUP"
```

You can also change the permissions so you can access this directory as a normal user:

```
sudo chmod 777 "/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme"
```

Comment: Not working anymore, please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/660855/how-can-you-change-unitys-theme-from-the-command-line That one worked for me

Comment: I was getting an error for the gsettings option, but I fixed it via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617561/problems-with-user-theme-gsettings-schemas