# How to add a theme entry in Ubuntu settings?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, desktop-background

I was making a Ubuntu/Gnome theme just for changing wallpapers putting  transition between wallpapers that got lost since Ubuntu 14.04 and some config files for changing the theme, now I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I wanted to know how to add an entry to that display menu in the Settings app.

I'm aware of `unity-tweak-tool` and that other third party software, I don't want to change my wallpapers I want to code that in my theme file. I know these entries are located somewhere because I have been able to change another system things just by writing some code in a XML file, please help.

[image: panel]

Comment: @Arun is not a duplicate because I want lines of code, not a third party software, I'm aware of ´unity-tweak-tool´ and I don't want to use it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/660855/how-can-you-change-unitys-theme-from-the-command-line

Comment: @RenatoA.  Settings app is hard-coded. Unless you alter the source code and recompile it, there's no way to make it recognize other themes. That's why 3rd party tools are used. You can, of course, use that Arun also posted - the `gsettings` command-line utility