# How do I execute a file as root using admin://

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, execute-command, administrator

I have this executable: `/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` which needs to run as root.

If I execute this with `sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` then it works fine.

I would like to add an entry to the application menu so that I can access this program without a terminal. In previous versions of Ubuntu I would use `gksudo` but this no longer exists in the latest version of Ubuntu. I was told the replacement for `gksudo` is `admin://`, so I tried both of these and neither work:

```
$ admin:///opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
bash: admin:///opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run: No such file or directory
$ admin://opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
bash: admin://opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run: No such file or directory
```

How do I use `admin://` to execute a program as root?

I also tried `pkexec` and it did not work correctly. This command works when executed in a terminal, but doesn't work when I add the exact code to a `.desktop` file using the menu editor:

```
pkexec --user root env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

Comment: `gksu` was depreciated some time ago (prior 17.04), normally replaced by `pkexec`, maybe useful will be https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo

Comment: @guiverc I just tried `pkexec` and it does not work because it can't find the display. I edited my question.

Comment: Some programs don't need `pkexec` in the command to run as root; for example, `gparted` and `gufw` will automatically ask for an admin password without it. What happens if you just add the executable to your .desktop file?

Comment: If I just run the executable, a message pops up that says "This application requires admin privileges".